# Protect .git file with git-bash

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, static-site

I'm trying to turn a django site into a static site using https://github.com/mgrp/django-distill . I am outputting the static files into

```
/e/ENVS/STATIC/static1
```

on my win10 local system. As I make changes I want to overwrite all the non hidden files including the `.git` directory, the commit and push the changes to my github repo for deployment. Unfortunately the distill project overwrites the entire directory , deleting the `.git/` files. I've tried to protect the git files with

```
$ chmod -R 707 .git/
```

using git-bash, but the output looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 197121     0 Oct 21 14:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 197121     0 Oct 20 17:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 197121     0 Oct 21 14:35 .git/
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 197121     0 Oct 21 14:36 .idea/
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 197121  9963 Oct 21 15:02 agreement.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 197121    17 Oct 21 15:02 contact.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 197121 14027 Oct 21 15:02 documents.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 197121 17048 Oct 21 15:02 form.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 197121 11060 Oct 21 15:02 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 me 197121  4921 Oct 21 15:02 slideshow.html
drwxr-xr-x 1 me 197121     0 Oct 21 15:02 static/
```

How do I turn on and off write permissions for the `.git/` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `.git/` folder out of the way elsewhere.

Whenever you need to work on that repo, set [the environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations):

```
GIT_DIR=/path/to/saved/.git
GIT_WORK_TREE=/where/your/.git/was
```

And you will benefit from working Git commands when typing `git status`, even if your deployment process overrides everything.